# Laravel creating zip with files on s3 bucket

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, php-ziparchive

So I've been trying to find a solution for this and I think it's got to do with the way I am creating the zip on the storage.

Controller:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');

        if($disk->exists('storage/mail_attachments/'.$this->zip_file)) {
            $disk->delete('storage/mail_attachments/'.$this->zip_file);
        }

        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($disk->put('storage/mail_attachments/'. $this->zip_file, ''), \ZipArchive::CREATE);

        $download_file = file_get_contents(config('filesystems.disks.s3.url') . '/storage/mail_attachments/user_form_'.$this->uf_id.'.pdf');

        $zip->addFromString(basename(config('filesystems.disks.s3.url') . '/storage/mail_attachments/user_form_'.$this->uf_id.'.pdf'), $download_file);
        $zip->close();
```

We are hosting this on Laravel vapor and see this in the logs:

`ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Read-only file system`

The code above manages to create the zip file but it's empty when viewing it. This was working fine using public_paths for creating the zip.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

**Update**

Managed to get it to work with the answer and Googled to find this thread which gave extra steps for making the zip https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vapor/zipping-file-on-laravel-vapor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to local file storage on lambda as it's serverless.

Create a new disk in your `config/filesystem.php`

```
'tmp' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => env('USE_LAMBDA_STORAGE', true) ? "/tmp" : storage_path('app/temp'),
  'url' => env('USE_LAMBDA_STORAGE', true) ? "/tmp" : storage_path('app/temp'),
],
```

Create the zip file there by using `$disk = Storage::disk('tmp');`.

Comment: I tried this and it's still throwing the error. I think Laravel vapor doesn't allow access to the storage_path.

Comment: It doesn't use the `storage_path` when you set `USE_LAMBDA_STORAGE` to `true` in your environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for this! I followed this thread which helped make the tmp of the zip and then transfer to the bucket I need it on. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vapor/zipping-file-on-laravel-vapor